# How can I get information from a JSON object that is enclosed in a list?

Tags: python, json, list, api

I made  a function that would ask users which school department they want to select, I would then use the input they have and put it into a get request and call the API in order to the classes available in, I would then dump the information using `dumps` and indent the lines so to make it easier to read. The problem I'm facing is that it puts the JSON in a list and I can no longer index it to get information.

This the code I have so far:

```
dept = input('what department are you  in right now: ')
dept = dept.upper()
if dept not in department_storage:
    raise ValueError("department doesn't exist")
else:
    department_url = requests.get(f"https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id={dept}")
    specific_major =department_url.json()
    cleaner_specific_major = json.dumps(specific_major, indent=2)
    print(cleaner_specific_major)
```

This is the JSON I get back:

```
[
  {
    "course_id": "INST123",
    "semester": "202008",
    "name": "Databases for All",
    "dept_id": "INST",
    "department": "Information Studies",
    "credits": "3",
    "description": "An introduction to relational databases for students with no previous programming experience. Provides a means for students of diverse backgrounds to successfully learn how to store, retrieve, and maintain data in relational databases. Topics include a brief comparison of database systems with an emphasis on relational databases, fundamental relational database concepts, and data types. Includes technical approaches to accessing information stored in relational databases.",
    "grading_method": [
      "Regular",
      "Pass-Fail",
      "Audit"
    ],
    "gen_ed": [
      "DSSP"
    ],
    "core": [],
    "relationships": {
      "coreqs": null,
      "prereqs": null,
      "formerly": null,
      "restrictions": null,
      "additional_info": null,
      "also_offered_as": null,
      "credit_granted_for": null
    },
    "sections": [
      "INST123-0101"
    ]
  },
```

Is there to index of get information out of this JSON list? 
I wanted to get the credits, name, section and course_id info out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may iterate over the dictionaries inside the list and extract the desired keys from each individually:

```
dept = input('what department are you  in right now: ')
dept = dept.upper()
if dept not in department_storage:
    raise ValueError("department doesn't exist")
else:
    department_url = requests.get(f"https://api.umd.io/v0/courses?dept_id={dept}")
    specific_major =department_url.json()
    keep_keys = ["course_id", "name", "credits", "sections"]                        
    courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
               for json_dict in specific_major]
    print(json.dumps(courses, indent=2))
```

Using `dept="INST"`, output:

```
[
  {
    "course_id": "INST123",
    "name": "Databases for All",
    "credits": "3",
    "sections": [
      "INST123-0101"
    ]
  },
  {
    "course_id": "INST126",
    "name": "Introduction to Programming for Information Science",
    "credits": "3",
    "sections": [
      "INST126-0101",
      "INST126-0102",
      "INST126-0103",
      "INST126-0104"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: thank you. do i put this for loop inside the else statement? is there a way to define them and then  put them in a dictionary to use in another function? greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, this goes inside your else statement as it handles the JSON response from your request. You could do something like in my update to add the course details to a list (a list of dictionaries), then you may do further processing with those later.

Comment: is there a way to indent the lines to make it more spaced out ? would adding.                          courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
               for json_dict in specific_major, indent = 2 ] be possible @dspencer

Comment: courses = [{k: json_dict[k] for k in keep_keys}
               for json_dict in specific_major, indent = 2 ] be possible @dspencer

Comment: No, the indent option is specific to outputting JSON using `json.dumps`. You may do something like `print(json.dumps(courses, indent=2))` to visualize in this way. It is not a property of the data structure itself, just a formatting parameter.

Comment: will do @dspencer i tried voting but my vote doesnt show.